# Trying to identify garage wall storage "system" that IS NOT slatwall or pegboard

Tags: garage, storage, identify-a-tool

I've googled how to identify "wall storage type," "hook type," "attachment type," etc., and all that EVER comes up are slatwall and pegboard, which look nothing like what I have.

[image]

The metal piece that is horizontally attached to the wall has two rows of hollow, vertical slots. A single hook/attachment piece has matching two rows of "hooked prongs" that slide down into wall slots (four slots/hooks each). I'd hate to spend money on something new if I can't find more attachments.

Comment: It looks more industrial/commercial than home use.  Maybe add that to your search might help.  Most searches will bring up home use stuff first.

Comment: look for manufacturer's labels

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google Lens recognizes your photo as "Tap-Mount", which seems to be correct, e.g. [image: Photo of Tap-Mount bracket]

(from https://www.knapeandvogt.com/tap-mount-shelf-brackets)

Comment: FYI, if you Google "John Sterling TAP-MOUNT" it looks like Menards and Home Depot carry it. Hope that helps find a local supplier.